# How to identify separate url in node js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I need to add conditionally `.ejs` file so I thought I could do it by two separate `.ejs` file but I got stuck to find out the difference in url,

I am always getting the same url from below code

```
req.originalUrl
```

I have url like this

```
localhost:4242/#!/home
localhost:4242/#!/user
localhost:4242/#!/profile
```

Is there any way to identify these page in node.js or any suggestion to handle above problem ?

I am looking to slit this code

```
ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/index.ejs'), pageOptions, {rmWhitespace: true}, function(err, html){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=UTF-8');
        res.end(html.split(">\n<").join("><")
            .split("}\n").join("}")
            .split("{\n").join("{")
            .split(";\n").join(";"));
    });
```

Into

```
 ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/index1.ejs')
 .....................
```

and

```
 ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, '../views/index2.ejs')
 .....................
```

Comment: Don't use `#` (which is client-only).

Comment: Everything after the `#` isn't send to the server. You could do an additional fetch to tell the server what page the user is on

Comment: @bambam : Please can you guide me more to do this ?

Comment: A hacky way to work with this is by setting a cookie

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev : thanks, I will try :)

Comment: A simple way to solve this is to change your URL scheme to "localhost:4242/app/home", "localhost:4242/app/user", "localhost:4242/app/profile" . You can use "app" or "x" or "ctrlf5" or any other string. Literally anything that does not contain "#"

Comment: @slebetman : thanks for suggestion, but that's a restriction I can't do like this.

Comment: I have no idea what your environment is. But hooking into angular's router and doing the request shouldn't be a problem